# Setting height of UIButton in Custom Table View Cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I've been making Custom Table View cells, but for both images and buttons whenever I create one, the height seems always to fill the cells height, with any frame created being ignored. I think i might be missing something obvious, but can't find the answer in any other thread. Using swift 5.

```
message = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 350, width: 120, height: 10))
message.setTitle("Chat", for: .normal)
message.backgroundColor = .clear
message.layer.cornerRadius = 5
message.layer.borderWidth = 1
message.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.71, blue:0.00, alpha:1.00).cgColor
message.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
message.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0.68, green:0.07, blue:0.83, alpha:1.00), for: .normal)
```

[image]

Comment: how you define `message` ?

Comment: var message = UIButton()

Answer (score 0):

This is linked to the way you add the `UIButton` to your Custom Table View. Do you define any anchor, NSLayoutConstraint?

If so, the frame you specify is overridden by the constraints defined.

Can you provide the way you add the UIButton to your `contentView`?